# Ruby: convert proc to lambda?

Tags: ruby, lambda, proc-object

Is it possible to convert a proc-flavored Proc into a lambda-flavored Proc?

Bit surprised that this doesn't work, at least in 1.9.2:

```
my_proc = proc {|x| x}
my_lambda = lambda &p
my_lambda.lambda? # => false!
```

Answer (score 22):

This one was a bit tricky to track down.  Looking at the docs for [`Proc#lambda?` for 1.9](http://ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/Proc.src/M001173.html), there's a fairly lengthy discussion about the difference between `proc`s and `lamdba`s.

What it comes down to is that a `lambda` enforces the correct number of arguments, and a `proc` doesn't.  And from that documentation, about the only way to convert a proc into a lambda is shown in this example:

> `define_method` always defines a method without the tricks, even if a non-lambda Proc  object is given. This is the only exception which the tricks are not preserved.
>
> ```
>  class C
>    define_method(:e, &proc {})
>  end
>  C.new.e(1,2)       => ArgumentError
>  C.new.method(:e).to_proc.lambda?   => true
> ```

If you want to avoid polluting any class, you can just define a singleton method on an anonymous object in order to coerce a `proc` to a `lambda`:

```
def convert_to_lambda &block
  obj = Object.new
  obj.define_singleton_method(:_, &block)
  return obj.method(:_).to_proc
end

p = Proc.new {}
puts p.lambda? # false
puts(convert_to_lambda(&p).lambda?) # true

puts(convert_to_lambda(&(lambda {})).lambda?) # true
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful :) The fact that define_method ultimately produced a lambda was what prompted my confusion.

Comment: Fun question time: how do you do this in jruby?

Comment: Answer to my fun question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239338/convert-bloc-to-lambda-in-jruby

Comment: If you're interested in getting this to be a stable interface. Can you please comment on this issue with why you wanted to convert a proc to a lambda in the first place? https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9777#change-46353

Answer (score 7):

It is *not* possible to convert a proc to a lambda without trouble. The answer by Mark Rushakoff doesn't preserve the value of `self` in the block, because `self` becomes `Object.new`. The answer by Pawel Tomulik can't work with Ruby 2.1, because `define_singleton_method` now returns a Symbol, so `to_lambda2` returns `:_.to_proc`.

My answer is *also wrong*:

```
def convert_to_lambda &block
  obj = block.binding.eval('self')
  Module.new.module_exec do
    define_method(:_, &block)
    instance_method(:_).bind(obj).to_proc
  end
end
```

It preserves the value of `self` in the block:

```
p = 42.instance_exec { proc { self }}
puts p.lambda?      # false
puts p.call         # 42

q = convert_to_lambda &p
puts q.lambda?      # true
puts q.call         # 42
```

But it fails with `instance_exec`:

```
puts 66.instance_exec &p    # 66
puts 66.instance_exec &q    # 42, should be 66
```

I must use `block.binding.eval('self')` to find the correct object. I put my method in an anonymous module, so it never pollutes any class. Then I bind my method to the correct object. This works though the object never included the module! The bound method makes a lambda.

`66.instance_exec &q` fails because `q` is secretly a method bound to `42`, and `instance_exec` can't rebind the method. One might fix this by extending `q` to expose the unbound method, and redefining `instance_exec` to bind the unbound method to a different object. Even so, `module_exec` and `class_exec` would still fail.

```
class Array
  $p = proc { def greet; puts "Hi!"; end }
end
$q = convert_to_lambda &$p
Hash.class_exec &$q
{}.greet # undefined method `greet' for {}:Hash (NoMethodError)
```

The problem is that `Hash.class_exec &$q` defines `Array#greet` and not `Hash#greet`. (Though `$q` is secretly a method of an anonymous module, it still defines methods in `Array`, not in the anonymous module.) With the original proc, `Hash.class_exec &$p` would define `Hash#greet`. I conclude that `convert_to_lambda` is wrong because it doesn't work with `class_exec`.

Answer (score 5):

Here is possible solution:

```rb
class Proc
  def to_lambda
    return self if lambda?

    # Save local reference to self so we can use it in module_exec/lambda scopes
    source_proc = self

    # Convert proc to unbound method
    unbound_method = Module.new.module_exec do
      instance_method( define_method( :_proc_call, &source_proc ))
    end

    # Return lambda which binds our unbound method to correct receiver and calls it with given args/block
    lambda do |*args, &block|
      # If binding doesn't changed (eg. lambda_obj.call) then bind method to original proc binding,
      # otherwise bind to current binding (eg. instance_exec(&lambda_obj)).
      unbound_method.bind( self == source_proc ? source_proc.receiver : self ).call( *args, &block )
    end
  end

  def receiver
    binding.eval( "self" )
  end
end

p1 = Proc.new { puts "self = #{self.inspect}" }
l1 = p1.to_lambda

p1.call #=> self = main
l1.call #=> self = main

p1.call( 42 ) #=> self = main
l1.call( 42 ) #=> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

42.instance_exec( &p1 ) #=> self = 42
42.instance_exec( &l1 ) #=> self = 42

p2 = Proc.new { return "foo" }
l2 = p2.to_lambda

p2.call #=> LocalJumpError: unexpected return
l2.call #=> "foo"
```

Should work on Ruby 2.1+

Answer (score 3):

Cross ruby compatiable library for converting procs to lambdas:
https://github.com/schneems/proc_to_lambda

The Gem:
http://rubygems.org/gems/proc_to_lambda

Answer (score 0):

The above code doesn't play nicely with `instance_exec` but I think there is simple fix for that. Here I have an example which illustrates the issue and solution:

```
# /tmp/test.rb
def to_lambda1(&block)
  obj = Object.new
  obj.define_singleton_method(:_,&block)
  obj.method(:_).to_proc
end

def to_lambda2(&block)
  Object.new.define_singleton_method(:_,&block).to_proc
end


l1 = to_lambda1 do
  print "to_lambda1: #{self.class.name}\n"
end
print "l1.lambda?: #{l1.lambda?}\n"

l2 = to_lambda2 do
  print "to_lambda2: #{self.class.name}\n"
end
print "l2.lambda?: #{l2.lambda?}\n"

class A; end

A.new.instance_exec &l1
A.new.instance_exec &l2
```

`to_lambda1` is basically the implementation proposed by Mark, `to_lambda2` is a "fixed" code.

The output from above script is:

```
l1.lambda?: true
l2.lambda?: true
to_lambda1: Object
to_lambda2: A
```

In fact I'd expect `instance_exec` to output `A`, not `Object` (`instance_exec` should change binding). I don't know why this work differently, but I suppose that `define_singleton_method` returns a method that is not yet bound to `Object` and `Object#method` returns an already bound method.