# Can I enforce arity on a block passed to a method?

Tags: ruby, lambda, proc

Is there any way to "turn on" the strict arity enforcement of a Proc instantiated using `Proc.new` or `Kernel.proc`, so that it behaves like a Proc instantiated with `lambda`?

My `initialize` method takes a block `&action` and assigns it to an instance variable. I want `action` to strictly enforce arity, so when I apply arguments to it later on, it raises an `ArgumentError` that I can rescue and raise a more meaningful exception. Basically:

```
class Command
  attr_reader :name, :action

  def initialize(name, &action)
    @name   = name
    @action = action
  end

  def perform(*args)
    begin
      action.call(*args)
    rescue ArgumentError
      raise(WrongArity.new(args.size))
    end
  end
end

class WrongArity < StandardError; end
```

Unfortunately, `action` does not enforce arity by default:

```
c = Command.new('second_argument') { |_, y| y }
c.perform(1) # => nil
```

`action.to_proc` doesn't work, nor does `lambda(&action)`.

Any other ideas? Or better approaches to the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to use `&action` at all.  Just delete the action parameter and on the line where you set the instance variable, replace `action` with `lambda`. I posted a code sample below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `@action` will be a `Proc` instance and `Proc`s have an [`arity`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Proc.html#method-i-arity) method so you can check how many arguments the block is supposed to have:

```
def perform(*args)
  if args.size != @action.arity
    raise WrongArity.new(args.size)
  end
  @action.call(*args)
end
```

That should take care of splatless blocks like `{ |a| ... }` and `{ |a,b| ... }` but things are a little more complicated with splats. If you have a block like `{ |*a| ... }` then `@action.arity` will be -1 and `{ |a,*b| ... }` will give you an `arity` of -2. A block with arity -1 can take any number of arguments (including none), a block with arity -2 needs at least one argument but can take more than that, and so on. A simple modification of splatless test should take care of the splatful blocks:

```
def perform(*args)
  if @action.arity >= 0 && args.size != @action.arity
    raise WrongArity.new(args.size)
  elsif @action.arity < 0 && args.size < -(@action.arity + 1)
    raise WrongArity.new(args.size)
  end
  @action.call(*args)
end
```

Comment: You're correct, this solves the problem. But I'm going to wait and see if there's a less verbose way to do it. The behavior I'm looking for is identical to lambda Procs, so I don't want to reimplement it if I don't have to (granted, my Command class is sort of already reimplementing Proc, but there will inevitably be more domain-specific behavior)

Comment: @rickyrickyrice: Yeah, it does seem a bit clunky but I can't think of anything better. OTOH, it is late here so I could be missing something obvious.

Comment: There is no other way other than use lambdas. That's how ruby is designed: proc has no arity checks. Starting from 1.9.2 ruby enforces proc arity validation.

Comment: I think it should be strictly less than for the second condition, because it is ok to pass 0 args to a proc of arity -1. Note also that you could combine the conditions to eliminate the `elsif`: `if (action.arity >= 0 && args.size != action.arity) || args.size < -(action.arity + 1)`

Comment: @AndyH: You're right on the `<` versus `<=` but I don't see any need to combine the branches, *shorter* doesn't mean *clearer*.

Comment: Agreed, but having the same code in each branch is also less than ideal. I think I would probably extract the condition into a separate method, `valid_arity?(args.size, action.arity)` or similar.

Comment: Ok I accepted it. But I think having to write code like this means I have problems with my design. I'm probably going to add a validation layer before execution even hits this code.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2946734/725792), the only way to convert a proc to a lambda is using `define_method` and friends. From the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Proc.html#method-i-lambda-3F):

> `define_method` always defines a method without the tricks [*i.e. a lambda-style Proc*], even if a non-lambda Proc object is given. This is the only exception for which the tricks are not preserved.

Specifically, as well as actually defining a method, `define_method(:method_name, &block)` returns a lambda. In order to use this without defining a bunch of methods on some poor object unnecessarily, you could use `define_singleton_method` on a temporary object.

So you could do something like this:

```
def initialize(name, &action)
  @name = name
  @action = to_lambda(&action)
end

def perform(*args)
  action.call(*args)
  # Could rescue ArgumentError and re-raise a WrongArity, but why bother?
  # The default is "ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)",
  # doesn't that say it all?
end

private

def to_lambda(&proc)
  Object.new.define_singleton_method(:_, &proc)
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Your solution:

```
class Command
  attr_reader :name, :action

  def initialize(name) # The block argument is removed
    @name   = name
    @action = lambda # We replace `action` with just `lambda`
  end

  def perform(*args)
    begin
      action.call(*args)
    rescue ArgumentError
      raise(WrongArity.new(args.size))
    end
  end
end

class WrongArity < StandardError; end
```

Some references: 
"If Proc.new is called from inside a method without any arguments of its own, it will return a new Proc containing the block given to its surrounding method."
-- http://mudge.name/2011/01/26/passing-blocks-in-ruby-without-block.html

It turns out that lambda works in the same manner.

Comment: Intriguing, but I don't think it works: (irb):7: warning: tried to create Proc object without a block

Comment: Actually I think it does work despite the warnings, but the fact that it does give these warnings suggests it's not an ideal solution!

Comment: So when I just copy/pasted the code sample (and ran the check in your OP), I didn't get any warnings.  But when I run it individually, I do.  As well, it only seems to convert blocks to lambdas, if it's passed a proc, it doesn't seem to convert it.

I think the above two solutions are almost definitely more kosher, but I don't see any problem with this if you are only converting blocks to lambdas and are always guaranteed a block.