# Learning Ruby from Python; Differences and Similarities

Tags: python, ruby

Inspired by [Learning Python from Ruby; Differences and Similarities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769004/learning-python-from-ruby-differences-and-similarities).

I'm in the exact opposite boat - I'm pretty well-versed in Python, but I need to start learning Ruby soon (and Rails later, but that's another topic). The question I'm linking to addresses this a bit, but are there any other resources out there that teach Ruby for someone who already has Python experience? (In other words, someone with a background in programming, but who doesn't yet know the difference between code that IRB will execute properly and proper Ruby code.)

**EDIT**: I'm not just looking for a list of the differences between the two languages - I'm wondering if there are any guides/walkthroughs that are directed towards teaching Python programmers to write idiomatic Ruby. I know similar guides exist for migrating *to* Python from other languages, but I don't know about Ruby.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While not targeted at Python programmers, you might find [this idomatic Ruby talk](http://cbcg.net/talks/rubyidioms/) useful.

(Related, but for Python: [Code Like a Pythonista: Idiomatic Python](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html))

Answer (score 7):

The Ruby website has [a page exactly on this topic](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/ruby-from-other-languages/to-ruby-from-python/). It's a summary list, so other answers with more best-practice style comments are surely a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for that - it's useful - but maybe I wasn't clear with my question. I'm looking for a resource to teach me how to write idiomatic code, not just a list of the differences. There may not even be one out there, but it's worth a shot.