# Ruby Arrays: keep repeated values only from the end of an array of arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays

If I have an array of arrays:

```
[[1, "foo"], [2, "bar"], [3, "foo"], [4, "foo"], [5, "bar"], [6, "baz"]]
```

How can I eliminate the repeated values, keeping the ones at the END of the array, resulting in:

```
[[4, "foo"], [5, "bar"], [6, "baz"]]
```

Thanks!

I have tried numerous approaches, such as following absurd lines, with no success.

```
a.delete_if {|q| q if q[1] in a}   # syntax error

a.each {|q| q.shift if q[1] in a[q][1]} # syntax error
```

and many more . . .

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "repeated values".  Based on your example, it appears you mean that `b` is a repeated value of `a` if `b` follows `a` and `b.last==a.last`.

Comment: FYI, the reason you're getting a syntax error is because "in" doesn't work like that in Ruby. I'm guessing you're looking for something similar to Array comprehensions in Python?

Comment: @Ajedi32, that's right, I'm relatively new to Ruby and learned to program in Python last year.

Comment: Cool. I don't want to get into too much detail here since the comments aren't really meant for extended discussion, but basically blocks in Ruby work a lot more like loops than Array comprehensions. This might interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4769004/1157054 And the reverse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769478/learning-ruby-from-python-differences-and-similarities?lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
a.reverse.uniq(&:last).reverse
=> [[4, "foo"], [5, "bar"], [6, "baz"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved by using Ruby's [`Hash`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html) technique also :

> A Hash is a dictionary-like collection of *unique keys and their values*. Also called associative arrays,....

```
array = [[1, "foo"], [2, "bar"], [3, "foo"], [4, "foo"], [5, "bar"], [6, "baz"]]
Hash[array].invert.map { |k,v| [v,k] } 
# => [[4, "foo"], [5, "bar"], [6, "baz"]]
```

**update** As @Uri suggested -

```
Hash[array].invert.invert.to_a
```

Comment: Why not simply `Hash[array].invert.invert.to_a`?

Answer (score 1):

```
 arr.group_by{|x|x[1]}.values.map(&:last)
```