# Where can I find good discussions of PHP vs Ruby vs Python?

Tags: php, python, ruby

Do you know about any *good* articles that discuss the differences between the languages? So far I've mostly found very non-neutral stuff or technical benchmarking of function X vs function Y.

Again, I'm not asking for arguments here for one language over another. I see there are a lot of similar questions, where the answer is basically that it's all about preference. What I'm looking for is maybe something where I can hear the reasoning behind the different languages matching people's preferences, etc.

Sorry if I'm being vague.

Comment: DHH's talk on ["Why Ruby"](http://confreaks.net/videos/431-rubyconf2010-keynote-why-ruby) really resounded with me; it's chock full of opinions, but may give some insight into the "preference" side of Ruby.

Comment: @Close voters: Two votes as off topic? Honestly? I know discussions shouldn't occur *on* Stack Overflow, but links to discussions should be fine.

Comment: @GWW: `PHP ruby python site:google.com` didn't get many relevant results. Oh, were you telling someone to google it? How about you google SO's FAQ?

Comment: @Andrew Grimm:  Your response is greatly appreciated and noted.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Python <-> Ruby: [What does ruby have that python doesnt and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113611/what-does-ruby-have-that-python-doesnt-and-vice-versa)
- Python <-> PHP: [is switching from php to python worth the trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486608/is-switching-from-php-to-python-worth-the-trouble)

Comment: This was a really great link, wish i'd found it before I posted.