# Is Perl weakly or strongly typed?

Tags: perl, typing

I am currently learning Perl 5 from learn.perl.org and I am curious about its typing system. I see mixed information about Perl being weakly or strongly typed, and that it is also dynamically typed. Wikipedia states that it also supports duck typing.

Can anyone confirm its weakly or strongly typed nature?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "weakly" and "strongly typed", and what you mean by "type" in relation to Perl.

Comment: Related: [Perl as a Strong-Type and Dynanmic Programming Language](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=857765) on Perl Monks.

Comment: Wondering why do you need this for the perl _learning_?

Answer (score 33):

> *I see mixed information about Perl being weakly or strongly typed*

That's no surprise given that there is also conflicting information as to whether C is a strongly-typed or weakly-typed language.

- An example for a statically, but **weakly** typed language is C. [[source](http://compilers.iecc.com/comparch/article/95-10-071)]
- C is **strongly** typed... [[source](http://ccs.njit.edu/%7Eelsa/280/280%20Lecture%2012%20became13_files/slide0138.htm+%22strongly+typed%22+%22%2Bc%22)]
- This works fine in **weakly** typed languages such as C. [[source](http://www.mvps.org/vb/hardcore/html/typelessvariables.htm)]
- LISP engines ...  are themselves generally written in **strongly** typed languages like C... [[source](http://tlug.linux.or.jp/ML/0010/msg00352.html)]
- In a **weakly** typed language such as C, ... [[source](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/%7Ediwan/5535-99/hw-6-soln.html)]
- TYPE: **strongly** typed: (C, Algol, Fortran) [[source](http://sweat.cs.unm.edu/%7Ebap/teach/S2000/CS257/notes/lecture/2000-01-19.txt)]

[Mark J Dominus](http://blog.plover.com/) [compiled](http://perl.plover.com/yak/12views/samples/slide043.html) the above list, and [discovered](http://perl.plover.com/yak/12views/samples/slide045.html) there are eight incompatible definitions for what it means to be strongly-typed.

1. A language is strongly typed if **type annotations are associated with variable names**, rather than with values. If types are attached to values, it is weakly typed.
2. A language is strongly typed if it contains **compile-time checks for type constraint violations**. If checking is deferred to run time, it is weakly typed.
3. A language is strongly typed if it contains **compile or run-time checks** for type constraint violations. If no checking is done, it is weakly typed.
4. A language is strongly typed if **conversions between different types are forbidden**. If such conversions are allowed, it is weakly typed.
5. A language is strongly typed if **conversions between different types must be indicated explicitly**. If implicit conversions are performed, it is weakly typed.
6. A language is strongly typed if there is **no language-level way to disable or evade the type system**. If there are casts or other type-evasive mechansisms, it is weakly typed.
7. A language is strongly typed if it has a **complex, fine-grained type system** with compound types. If it has only a few types, or only scalar types, it is weakly typed.
8. A language is strongly typed if the **type of its data objects is fixed and does not vary** over the lifetime of the object. If the type of a datum can change, the language is weakly typed.

This goes to show that "strongly-typed" and "weakly-typed" are [meaningless phrases](http://perl.plover.com/yak/12views/samples/slide046.html). As such, the rest of this answer and all other answers are really just guesses at what you are asking.

---

> *Is Perl weakly or strongly typed?*

It has both strong types (scalar, array, hash, etc) and weak types (string, floating point number, signed integer, unsigned integer, references, etc).

This is based on definitions #1, #2, #4, #5 and #6 from the above list.

---

> *Wikipedia states that it also supports duck typing.*

Method calls do indeed utilize dynamic binding ([duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)).

This means the method called by `$o->method` is based on the current value of `$o`, rather than one associated with `$o` itself.

As far as I know, the definition for this is unambiguous.

Comment: Absolutely agree.  The notion originated and may have had a meaning 20 or 30 years ago, when the computing landscape was a hundred-fold smaller.

Comment: That's very helpful. As new programming languages optimized for specific tasks are developed, we lose to ability to draw distinct lines between antiquated concrete categories.

Comment: Neither C (1972) nor Perl (1987) are new programming languages.

Answer (score 5):

If you use the definition of 'strongly typed' that means you specify what type of data a variable holds - perl isn't.

It basically has one type - scalar - which can hold a variety of different data types. Perl infers correctness of operation based on what it 'looks like'.  (It also has hash and array - which are groups of scalars)

Because you can:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $value = 42;

#concat 0 onto the end. 
$value .= 0;
print $value,"\n";
#numeric add
$value += 1;
print $value,"\n";
#division - to create a float.
$value = $value / 4;
print $value,"\n";
#string replacement on a float. 
$value =~ s/\.25//g;
print $value,"\n";
```

Which implicitly casts `$value` back and forth between string and number, and it 'just works' - I call it weakly typed.

These are operations that ... wouldn't work (the way you expect) in a strongly typed language because of the type mismatching.

One thing perhaps worth mentioning as related is the notion of [context](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context). Perl is a context sensitive language, in that it infers what you mean from the context.

So if you simply open and read from a file handle:

```
open ( my $input, '<', "some_file.txt" ) or die $!;
my $line = <$input>;
```

This will read a single line from `$input` because it's doing a read in a *scalar* context.

And if you instead do:

```
my @lines = <$input>;
```

Because you're working in a list context, the entirelty of the file is read into the array `@list`.

You can explicitly test context using `wantarray()` (which is a misnomer - it should really be `wantlist`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

sub context_test {

   if ( wantarray() ) {
       return ( "some", "results", "here", "(list context)" );
   }
   else {
      if ( defined wantarray() ) {
          return "some results (scalar context)"; 
      }
      else {
           print "called in a void context\n";
      }
   }
}

my $first = context_test;
print Dumper \$first;

my @second = context_test;
print Dumper \@second;

context_test;
```

I would I think also call this an example of weak typing, in that perl *tries* to figure out the right thing to do, based on context. And sometimes it does get this wrong.

So you can:

```
print "Elements are:", @second, "\n"; # prints elements from the array.
print "Count is", scalar @second,"\n"; #prints number of elements in array.
if ( @second > 2 ) { 
   print "Array \@second has more than 2 elements\n";
}
```

The reason I mention it is (aside from a comment) context may also be coerced by operator type.

```
$first .= @second; #forces scalar context due to concat operation.
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'd say everything is a scalar when you have to explicitly cast objects as scalars.  Puzzling out things like `grep` or even the `=~` operator are a bitch when they act differently in "scalar context."  And then there is the difference between casting a list as a scalar and getting a reference to the list.

Comment: Hmm, scalar vs. list context is something that I'll perhaps include. I don't think it really applies to a discussion about typing though, because a list is still just a collection of scalars.

Comment: Going to have to disagree with you there -- why is "collection of scalars" not a type? What do you mean by "type"?

Comment: Re "*I would I think also call this an example of weak typing, in that perl tries to figure out the right thing to do, based on context*", That's not remotely close to [any definition](http://perl.plover.com/yak/12views/samples/slide045.html) or weakly typed I've ever seen. I agree with your original assessment that this is unrelated to the "discussion".

Comment: @trentcl, All subs return a number of scalars. All values and variables here are of type scalar. There's no "collection of scalar" value or variable.

Comment: @stevesliva, Polymorphism is allowed in both strongly- and weakly-typed languages, so the fact that `grep` and `=~` are polymorphic is irrelevant.

Comment: @ikegami trying to make the discussion more useful regardless of the precise question at hand.   "Everything is a scalar" in practice seems to bump into issues on any man page that mentions "context."  You may be right that I opened this can of worms in the wrong context though.

Comment: @ikegami `@lines` and `@second` are variables, but they are not scalars. Subroutines are not scalars. Hashes are not scalars. Claiming that Perl "basically has one one type - scalar" calls into question the definition of "type", since it's not the same one being used by... well, most people. I'm just looking for clarification

Comment: @trentcl, I fully agree. I have no idea why Sobrique says there's only one type. [ Even in Perl's C code, arrays and scalars are different types. ...Kinda. An array (`AV*`) is really a scalar (`SV*`) of type `SVt_PVAV`, and you can use a cast to switch between the two. But that's two levels removed from Perl; it has no bearing here. ]