# Don't quite understand this leetcode problem

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, while-loop

This probably isn't necessarily Ruby exclusive, but I have a sort of lingering question here that I most recently came across with Ruby.

```
# @param {Integer[]} nums
# @return {Integer[]}
def running_sum(nums)
    i = 0
    while i < nums.length - 1
        nums[i+1] = nums[i] + nums[i+1]
        i += 1
    end
    nums
end
```

The goal of this is to gather a "running sum." I understand the logic, but this syntax is confusing me. Here's what I'm understanding:

"This method is called running_sum and has an array called nums (which presumably contains numbers). We will start counting these numbers at zero. While what we are counting is less than the total amount of numbers in our array less one, we will loop through our starting point and the one array location that follows. We will also add that following number to our carried total while we loop through it. Our final total is equal to the location we ended after looping through the array. Show me that final total. We're done here"

I believe I get the overall logic, but for the sake of replication, I'd like to know why the letter i is being used here. As I understand it, it is similar to a variable we would use in algebra. Is my understanding accurate? Or am I just way off on this?

Comment: does ruby allow for `nums[i+1] .= nums[i+1]` or `nums[i+1] += nums[i+1]`?

Comment: The letter i in programming terms has been used as a variable name representing a whole number numeric value for counting since the seventies where it was typically shorthand to describe a variable of type integer in strongly typed languages such as COBOL, x is another common counter variable name but you can use whatever you want instead of the letter i you could replace it with the words my_counter or whatever you feel describes your usage. By the way, your assumption regarding nums containing integers is wrong, it could contain letters, words, a hash or even an array of arrays

Comment: It goes even further than the seventies. In Fortran (1957), the type of a variable is given by the first letter of the variable name, e.g. variable names starting with `I`…`N` are integers, all others are reals. Therefore, `I` is the lexicographically first, shortest, variable name that defines an integer variable.

Comment: @JörgWMittag It goes back even further than that because FORmulaTRANslator was trying to map longstanding mathematical indexing concepts from vectors and matrices into a computing context.

Comment: Might I suggest a more succinct title for the question? Something to show that you’re asking about variable naming, or specifically the use of `i` as a variable name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# @param {Integer[]} nums
# @return {Integer[]}
def running_sum(nums) 
    i = 0
    while i < nums.length - 1
        nums[i+1] = nums[i] + nums[i+1]
        i += 1
    end
    nums
end
```

The method called `running_sums` is an instance method that accepts a parameter called nums. The content of the variable called nums could be absolutely anything so you need to take care of that e.g. whate happens if `some_object.running_sums` is called using the following parameter `%w{word1, word2, word3}`

```
some_object = SomeClass.new
some_object.running_sums(%w{word1, word2, word3})
```

By the way it would be better if running_sums was a class method rather than an instance method

```
def self.running_sum(nums) 
  #etc ...
end
```

To enable you to do

SomeClass.running_sums

You need to remember that Ruby is NOT strongly typed.

Most other languaes are strongly typed, Java, C, C++, C#, PASCAL, COBOL, Delphi, VisualBasic to name a tiny few you need to define a variable name before it is used and set the type of variable to be something like an integer or a string or a decimal then that variable will reserve a memory slot that can only accept values of the type you've set.
In strongly typed languages you could provide a variable name and call it what you want but define it as an integer and it will only accept whole numbers. e.g. `var MyWord: integer` will mean you can only assign whole numbers. In some languages only positive whole numbers, negative whole numbers would have a different type. There will be a compiler that will not generate the exe or whatever the end result would be and throw an error if you tried to assign a value of the wrong type this is not so in Ruby.

In Ruby you can just make up a word and stuff a value of any type you want into it at any time and just because you give the variable a name such as my_number it will not stop someone stuffing words or letters into it such as my_number = "A cat sat on a wall" which is totally valid and clearly not a number.

So yes, it is a bit like algebra, the letter i usually denotes an integer type but be careful in Ruby cos it could be anything, it is just a memory block containing 0's and 1's.

The above is not strictly true but it should give you the right idea.

Comment: Your statement "Ruby is NOT strongly typed" [is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/520398/2166798).  It is not statically typed, but is more strongly typed than C where you can access any chunk of memory in any way you like via pointers, despite the static compile-time declarations.

Comment: [This 4 minute presentation is tongue-in-cheek](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/useing-youre-types-good), but has some teeth.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to know why the letter i is being used here.

`i` is usually the standard 'counter' variable name in imperative programming, short for 'index' (e.g. the array at index `i` being `nums[i]`)

Comment: It's actually short for Integer

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to know why the letter i is being used here.

It's a lazy and old habit.

Here, it's representative that you're dealing with an integer, and that can be fine for the sake of a brief code exercise.

But, you can do better in your own code.

> There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things.
>
> -- Phil Karlton

In an abstract coding exercise, it's hard to name things properly without real applied, context. So the author went with "Integer" as the name and shortened it. But when you're applying this in the real world you will have a use case which can, and should, inspire your naming of things beyond the 'type' of the variable.

This is not ruby specific, but the ruby community (I find) more than other communities favours very long and descriptive method and variable names. So, use long descriptive names of the variables when you're applying your learning in your production code.

Comment: Never saw that quote before, but I love it. As a musician, I can tell you that I know countless songs. But don't you dare ask me what songs I know because I'm not even consciously aware that I know any songs at all. Specifically within the context of a setlist for a given event. I feel the same exact sense of cluelessness when it comes to naming things in code. My chicken scratch notes on data-flow/app structure is reminiscent of a 5-year-old's story-telling ethics.